# How to find a path with fewest turn in OSMNX?

Tags: python, networkx, path-finding, osmnx

In OSMNX, we can derive the street angle in a road network, so that each edge in the network has a bearing attribute. I am trying to find a path that has the fewest turn (simplest path) from a specific source to a specific destination. That is the path that has the least angularity (total change of course direction)

I knew that we could use shortest path algorithm such as Dijkstra in osmnx and networkx. However, the weight parameter can only measure the distance in the street (edge). It cannot measure the angle between two streets (edge) as expected in the simplest path with fewest turn.

This is my code so far:

```py
import numpy as np
import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ox.config(log_console=True, use_cache=True)
%matplotlib inline

G = ox.graph_from_place('Turi, Sleman, Yogyakarta, Indonesia', network_type='drive', simplify=False)

G = ox.core.add_edge_lengths(G)
G = ox.add_edge_bearings(G)

route = nx.shortest_path(G, 3728658006, 5388482029, weight='bearing')
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph_route(G, route, node_size=0, fig_height=10)
```

The expected result should come with a path that has the fewest turn in term of total change in course direction.

Comment: You can try converting the graph to a dual-graph where the edges become nodes and the nodes become edges. Then if somehow you can assign the value of the bearing between the 2 edges (which is a node) in the old graph to the edge representing that node in the dual graph, and consequently run a dijkstra's shortest path algorithm with weight = bearing, then you will get the shortest path.

Comment: NetworkX has a function called line_graph which does this, and although this can be applied in case of OSM graphs as shown in https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/master/notebooks/08-example-line-graph.ipynb, I have never applied it myself on an OSM network. You could try though.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way is to impose turn penalty to each turn, so the shortest path algorithm minimizes both the travel time and the numbers of turns.

A transportation paper adapted the shortest path algorithm to consider the turning penalty, basically by keeping track of the next node to go and adding in the turn penalty in advance: Ziliaskopoulos, A.K., Mahmassani, H.S., 1996. A note on least time path computation considering delays and prohibitions for intersection movements. Transportation Research Part B: Methodological 30, 359–367. https://doi.org/10.1016/0191-2615(96)00001-X

This avoids exploding each node for turn movement which would result in a much bigger network.

I have implemented this by adapting the Dijkstra in the NetworkX package: https://github.com/maxtmng/shortest_path_turn_penalty/